# Dominant seventh without dominant of dominant

Tags: chords, chord-theory

It is to say a dominant seventh without the degree II of root tonality.

For example, in Clara Schumann's lied *Was weinst du, Blümlein*, we have B-A-B-D#. In this bar we are in E major ; this chord seems like a dominant seventh without F#. How can I make its chord notation (with roman numerals) ?

[Full score](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/7/75/IMSLP485202-PMLP786230-Clara_Schumann_Sechs_Lieder_aus_Jucunde_von_Hermann_Rollet_Op.23.pdf) (p. 2, system 2)

[image]

Comment: The key of this piece is A major.  The tonicization of the dominant is typically regarded as temporary, especially at the end of the first or second phrase as in this instance, so the B7 chord is is V7/V, and the missing fifth of that chord is the sixth degree of the scale, not the second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A chord will need its root present - otherwise we don't know what to call it.

It needs its third, as without that, we don't know if it's a major or minor chord.

If it's a seventh chord, it obviously needs that 7th note - of some sort - here m7, making the chord dominant seventh, as you anticipate.

There is often the omission of the 5th (P5) from a chord, as that pitch is present in the harmonics of the root, and is the first, generally, to go, in a complex chord. Obviously, if it's ♯5 or ♭5, it'll need to be there, but in a 'standard' chord, it adds not that much to the sound (unless it's a 'power chord', but that's a different kettle of fish!

So B, D♯ and A notes are sufficient to make the B7 chord, in just about any genre of music.

EDIT: apparently the piece is in key A, so the B7 chord would more likely be in RN seen as V7/V. Thanks to phoog.

Comment: Thank you for this quick and precise answer! Therefore, I should notate it V +7, right ?

Comment: In older music, it's common for the third to be absent, especially on final chords (by which point, if you haven't noticed whether the key or mode has a minor or major third, there are perhaps other problems afoot).  I would add that Roman numeral analysis doesn't purport to describe chords so precisely as to differentiate those with the fifth omitted from those that include the fifth, so not only is this B7 but it is also V7/V.

Comment: Simply V7. The +could confuse readers into thinking it's an augmented chord.

Comment: @phoog - OP says that this bar is in key E, so V7 will suffice. Were it in key A, then yes, V7/V. And without more of the dots, who knows?

Comment: I understand. @Tim, in France we are used to write the dominant seventh in root position as "V +7", the "+" meaning we added the leading tone.

Comment: Tim: the score of the entire song is linked in the question.  This isn't a key change just as the raised fourth degree on "dawn's early light" in the "Star-Spangled Banner" isn't a key change.  @Lava the seventh of V7 isn't the leading tone; the third of V7 is the leading tone.  The seventh of V7 is the fourth degree of the scale.

Comment: @Lava oh I see, the + represents the major third of the chord, as  would a sharp sign in figured bass.  In English language literature, at least, this is unnecessary because the roman numeral itself indicates the quality of the third -- upper case for major and lower case for minor (e.g., ii7 is a minor seventh chord).  If you write the 7 vertically above the plus sign as in the example I found online, it would not likely be taken as indicating an augmented interval, but it might indeed be confusing; I would perhaps use a sharp sign instead if possible if writing for an international audience.

Comment: @phoog OK, I was not aware of these differences in chord writing.

So this raised fourth does not imply a modulation towards E major? In this case, the dominant seventh chord of the dominant should be written V7/V? I didn't know this way of notating chords.

Comment: @Lava - I've checked through ways of the French labelling dominant 7ths and found no references to V+7 anywhere. I've been using the French system for nearly a decade now, and never come across it. Please enlighten me.

Comment: @Tim You may check out this: https://www.apprendrelesolfege.com/chiffrage-d-accords-a-4-sons

Comment: Still not convinced! I play with a lot of French musos, and none have come across this. Simple question - if that's true, how would one write C dominant 7 with an augmented 5th?

Comment: I don't know, maybe V 7+#5? I am a humble conservatory student and we learnt to notate the 1st inversion of dominant seventh chord V 7+ like shown in the link above or here : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_de_septi%C3%A8me_de_dominante_avec_fondamentale, that's all I can tell you. I am not experienced enough to go further ^^